# Why formData does not work with multiple files?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, multer, form-data

I'm facing a problem with a React project I'm working on: I'm trying to upload multiple images to a Node Express API. I'm using a formData object and I used the `append()` method to append the form fields from the component State.

In the Express code I'm using multer, all the attributes in the `req.body` are there but `req.files` is empty.

I changed the code to upload a single image also using formData() and it works; the problem seems to be only when I try with multiple files using the formData object. I also tested using a regular form (not react) and that also worked!

I'm wondering if there is something I'm missing when I use formData with a file input with multiple files?

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

class Form extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { images: {} };
  }

  onChangeImages = e => {
    this.setState({ images: e.target.files })
  };

  onSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const { images } = this.state;

    const formData = new FormData();

    formData.append("images", images);

    axios
      .post("/api/post/create", formData)
      .then(res => console.log(res.data))
      .catch(err => console.error(err));
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>

        <input
          onChange={this.onChangeImages}
          type="file"
          name="images"
          multiple
          accept="image/png, image/jpeg, image/jpg"
        />

        <br />
        <input type="submit" value="Send" />
      </form>
    );
  }
}

export default Form;
```

---

Express code

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const multer = require('multer');
const upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' });


router.post('/create', upload.array('images', 2), (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.files);
    console.log(req.body);
    res.status(200).json(req.body);
});


module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

> ```
> formData.append("images", images);
> ```

You need to append each file in turn. `FormData` doesn't support a `FileList` object.

```
for (let i = 0 ; i < images.length ; i++) {
    formData.append("images", images[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using "upload.array", in the backend side you need something like this

```
   let arrayImages = [];
     for (let i = 0; i < req.files.length; i++) {
       let k = path.join(req.files[i].filename);
       arrayImages.push(k)
   }

    images: arrayImages,
```